# UICollectionView Cell Internally loaded but UICollectionView is not Showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Seems cell is loaded internally but , UICollectionView does not appear .

`CollectionViewCell.xib and CollectionResuableView.xib` also be included in the project .

CollectionView is the remains of black.

Why it is not working? I have use Xcode 6 and use below code.

---

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CollectionReusableView.h"
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self _setup];
}

- (void)_setup{
    self.collectionView.delegate = (id)self;
    self.collectionView.dataSource = (id)self;
     [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionReusableView" bundle:nil] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"Section"];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 3;
}

- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {
        CollectionReusableView *sectionView = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"Section" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        sectionView.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section%ld", indexPath.section + 1];
        return sectionView;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (CollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                          cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: @"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row: %li",(long)indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@",[cell.label debugDescription]);
    return cell;
}
@end
```

NSLog(@"%@",[cell.label debugDescription]);

```
2014-11-11 14:54:46.899 collectionViewSample[7242:1226917] <UILabel: 0x7fd492c54af0; frame = (58 14; 42 21); text = 'Row: 0'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fd492c54c50>>
2014-11-11 14:54:46.900 collectionViewSample[7242:1226917] <UILabel: 0x7fd492c58850; frame = (58 14; 42 21); text = 'Row: 1'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fd492c589b0>>
2014-11-11 14:54:46.900 collectionViewSample[7242:1226917] <UILabel: 0x7fd492c5c5c0; frame = (58 14; 42 21); text = 'Row: 2'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fd492c5c720>>
2014-11-11 14:54:46.901 collectionViewSample[7242:1226917] <UILabel: 0x7fd492c60360; frame = (58 14; 42 21); text = 'Row: 3'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fd492c604c0>>
2014-11-11 14:54:46.901 collectionViewSample[7242:1226917] <UILabel: 0x7fd492c64130; frame = (58 14; 42 21); text = 'Row: 4'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fd492c64290>>
2014-11-11 14:54:46.902 collectionViewSample[7242:1226917] <UILabel: 0x7fd492c67d20; frame = (58 14; 42 21); text = 'Row: 5'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fd492c67e80>>
2014-11-11 14:54:46.902 collectionViewSample[7242:1226917] <UILabel: 0x7fd492c6bac0; frame = (58 14; 42 21); text = 'Row: 6'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fd492c6bc20>>
2014-11-11 14:54:46.903 collectionViewSample[7242:1226917] <UILabel: 0x7fd492c6f8a0; frame = (58 14; 42 21); text = 'Row: 7'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fd492c6fa00>>
2014-11-11 14:54:46.903 collectionViewSample[7242:1226917] <UILabel: 0x7fd492c73610; frame = (58 14; 42 21); text = 'Row: 8'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fd492c73770>>
2014-11-11 14:54:46.904 collectionViewSample[7242:1226917] <UILabel: 0x7fd492c771d0; frame = (58 14; 42 21); text = 'Row: 9'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fd492c77330>>
```

Comment: It was possible to display when you change the size of ContentView of Cell in IB.

Answer (score 0):

Collectionview is not appearing so i think there is a problem in collectionview layout so at first implement delegate UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout in your viewcontroller and try to add few delegate methods of collectionview to check whether it is firing its delegate properly so it will help you .

Comment: Add UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout in ViewController , but the problem could not be resolved .

Comment: numberOfSectionsInCollectionView , viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind , numberOfItemsInSection and cellForItemAtIndexPath is firing.

Answer (score 0):

In the two work days I spent searching for the cause of "black rectangle" for UICollectionView when all delegate methods etc. are working, I twice read every SO entry about "UICollectionView" and "black" and there are *many* still unanswered.  Choosing this question as more recent:  in IB/XIB, Storyboard, Attributes Inspector for the UICollectionView, scroll down to the View section, change Background from Default to another color, and rebuild.
    I conclude it frequently happens that when first testing a UICollectionView to see if you can make it work, with a default Label (black text) and possibly default Image (possibly without yet assigning an actual image to it, or possibly of dark color or transparent) in the UICollectionViewCell, the simulator displays the black rectangle, so you conclude your new code is broken when problem is simple graphics.